# How can I access a storage buffer using non aligned offset?

Tags: glsl, vulkan, hlsl

I have a storage buffer that contains packed pixels in BGR format (3 bytes per pixel).

I would like to write a simple compute shader that writes each pixel to a RGBA texture.

However, I could not find a way to access a non aligned address in a shader (either glsl or hlsl).

HLSL for example has ByteAddressBuffer, but its Load functions require addresses to be 4 bytes aligned.

```
ByteAddressBuffer inputBuffer : register(t0); // bgr, 3 bytes per pixel
RWTexture2D<float4> outputTexture : register(u1); // rgba unorm texture

[numthreads(16, 16, 1)]
void main(uint3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    // Calculate the coordinates of the current thread in the output texture
    uint2 texCoord = dispatchThreadID.xy;

    // Calculate the starting byte offset of the pixel in the input buffer
    uint byte_offset = texCoord.x + texCoord.y * 1024; // 1024 is image width

    // Read the B, G, and R values from the input buffer - doesn't work
    uint bgr_value = inputBuffer.Load(byte_offset);
    ...
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's plausible that a lot of hardware doesn't have support for such functionality, and so GLSL wasn't given support for it. Of course you can also read 4/8 bytes, then shift around and OR the values. You might face some challenges with endianness, but almost everything uses little-endian these days.

Comment: @vandench-onstrike almost all hardware support this as they support opencl / cuda which have this capability. On AMD there are assembly commands to load a single byte. it is true however that loading non 4 bytes aligned data is not always optimal.

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes, almost all modern desktop hardware is going to support byte level access, but Vulkan and GLSL weren't designed for modern desktop hardware, they were designed to support a broad range of hardware, thus to some degree they have to support the lowest common denominator. Of course this is why it is so great that Vulkan supports extensions. I simply offered an extension free option.

Answer (score 2):

To have data (and access to them) smaller than 4 bytes in a shader storage buffer, you'll need to enable `VK_KHR_8bit_storage` or `VK_KHR_16bit_storage` (and of course check for it - as far as I can tell, just about any modern Desktop GPU has support for it, though support on mobile GPUs looks to be more bleak). Using std430 should then allow you to access individual bytes of your pixel array. In GLSL, the data types are uint8_t etc. Don't forget to put `#extension GL_EXT_shader_8bit_storage: require`.

That being said, I'd like to pitch the idea of processing multiple (e.g. four, loading 3*4 bytes at once) pixels per thread instead. Loading individual bytes may carry a performance penalty that may or may not matter for your use case.

Comment: indeed in compute processing batch of 4 pixels per compute invocation was the faster solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed ByteAddressBuffer requires load to be 4 bytes aligned (anything else is undefined behaviour).

If you cannot use extensions (I don't think there is one in DirectX), you have 2 options:

- If you process pixel per pixel, you need to check if address is 4 bytes aligned, if yes, just load it as it is, if not, you need to perform 2 loads and merge the pixel with some bit shift magic.
- Since you use compute, you are allowed to write to several pixels at once, so you can load 4 pixels in a row (4*3 = 12, 4 bytes alignment is guaranteed), then write those 4 pixels.

I remember implementing both and second one was much faster.